# Boost Asio and usage of OpenSSL in multithreaded app

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, openssl, boost-asio

My app uses Boost.Asio to communicate with the server over TLS (so it uses OpenSSL). But I am planning to use OpenSSL in different thread to cipher some data (not related to communication with the server).

Docs for OpenSSL say that library requires some configuration before use within multithreaded app. Should I provide this configuration or Boost.Asio does it for me? Do I have any limitations in my scenario?

Comment: The last time I checked, Boost is not thread safe. Things may have changed since I last investigated it and audited the code.

Comment: See my answer on the post that I reference to mark this as a duplicate. Answers all of your question(s).